# Do CC troops have tombstones for 20 Elixir/1 Elixir when they die trying to protect the village?

Tags: clash-of-clans

If a Dragon comes out of the CC and gets killed by Wizards, then does it form a tombstone? Do attack reinforcements have tombstones as well?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, any clan castle reinforcements whether used on defense or offense spawn tombstones upon their death.